# java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect error in JAVA and same logic working fine in .NET

Tags: java

I found many articles with similar error but nothing helps (or I couldn't find the suitable one)

**Brief info of the issue**
Connection timed out: connect error observed while trying to get the Azure token

1. The same java code is working fine in **A** environment and not working in **B** environment
2. From B environment, I was able to access that URL from Browser (IE), Able to get the token from Postman, also able to get the token from .NET Code

Initially I thought there is some firewall/proxy issue in **B** environment, but once it is started working from Postman/>NET code not sure what i have to check now

What are the possibilities to get into this issue ? From where we need to start debugging in this situation ?

Stack trace

{java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

```
            at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)

            at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)

            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)

            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)

            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)

            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)

            at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)

            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)

            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)

            at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)

            at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)

            at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)

            at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)

            at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)

            at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)

            at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)

            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)

            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)

            at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)

            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1316)

            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1291)

            at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)}
```

It is failing from “connectResult = connect0(nativefd, address, port)”. unable to debug further from that method.

With full debug option in java level , last successful message is below then we got the timeout issue

FINEST: Creating new HttpsClient with url: https://login.microsoftonline.com/567abcde-3214-4grr-8e51-414b68ebb796/oauth2/v2.0/token

and proxy:DIRECT with connect timeout:-1

Can anyone suggest where we need to start our investigation ?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no other problem, Connection Timeout could also be caused by firewall. Are you sure your JDK/JRE is included in the exceptions of your firewall for outgoing connections?